# jquery setup with Symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony

I am trying to set up a simple jquery for my symfony platform. Just trying to implement this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_p to see if everything works fine.

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}TEST JQUERY{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("p").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>


<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>


{% endblock %}
```

when i do view source on the page, the structure seems fine but the jquery is not being executed.

Comment: Did you check the console of your browser web tools? Is the Jquery file included? Maybe some other errors are echoed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery you are including doesn't exist on google's CDN

Use `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead.

If you are wanting version `1.9.1`, get if from [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/download/) at [this link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js)

Comment: thank you for pointing out this.. i found the jquery link from the http://jquery.com/download/ page..
which displays as script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   .. i should have paid more attention.. Thanks again

Comment: Ah okay, I just noticed it too. Maybe Google will update their CDN soon.

Answer (score 1):

Change the jquery function and try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").live('click', function(){
            $("p").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

### update

As **rrikesh** pointer out since live is deprecated after v1.7, you may want to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "button", function (){
        $("p").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated

Comment: actually in 1.9 (which he's using) is removed, not just deprecated

Comment: Thanks for fixing, but I think the problem here is a bad link to jquery as I [mentionned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14705506/1370034). I got a 404 trying to access it and I just checked: Google CDN stops at version 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

This could be a better solution:

```
<script src="{{ asset('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script><window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"\{\{ asset(\'../app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js\') \}\}\"><\/script>')</script>
```

And download the `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` file to your `app/Resources/public/js/vendor/` directory.

In this way, the client always gets the source.